# Puppet can't copy a file from a module

Tags: puppet

I try to copy a file from a module :

```
#init.pp
file { '/home/michael/projets/test_puppet/LICENSE':
        source  => 'puppet:///modules/java/LICENSE',
        replace => false,
}
```

But when I run puppet apply

```
puppet apply --modulepath=/home/michael/projets/test_puppet/modules/  manifests/init.pp
```

I get this error

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/home/michael/projets/test_puppet/LICENSE]: 
Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production 
source(s) puppet:///modules/java/LICENSE
```

My directory structure

```
.
├── manifests
│   └── init.pp
└── modules
    ├── java
    └── stdlib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this path `puppet:///modules/java/LICENSE`, the file should be under

```
/home/michael/projets/test_puppet/modules/java/files/LICENSE
```

Could you please confirm if you have the file `LICENSE` in above path.

Please go through the docs [The Puppet File Server](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html), it will help you to understand how it works.

Comment: You were right, I didn't understand it. I create the "files" directory and copy the "LICENCE" file inside for the test and it worked. Thanks for the doc reference, I'm going to read it.